# Using 'for loop'

Tags: python, json, foursquare

How can I use 'for loop'  to get multiple values of lng and lat for more than one address?

Here I have only one address. What if I have 13 other addresses and I want all their corresponding [lat, lng] as output. By the way, I have used necessary libraries like 'geopy', etc (not important here I guess)

```
address = 'Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo'
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare_agent")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
latitude = location.latitude
longitude = location.longitude
print(latitude, longitude)

59.922816 10.700466
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the addresses, accessing one address at a time. Here is a pseudocode since your question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
addresses = ['Nobels gate 32, N-0268 Oslo', ....]
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare_agent")
for add in addresses:
    location = geolocator.geocode(add)
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    print(latitude, longitude)
```